# compress avi video with c#

Tags: c#, .net, compression, avi

I have an AVI file that I would like to compress.

I have tried using [Simple C# Wrapper for the AviFile Library](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7388/A-Simple-C-Wrapper-for-the-AviFile-Library) but it was problematic because of 2 reasons:

- while compression, the infrastructure pops up a form window to choose a compression method, and I can't chooce the compression method by code
- The compression makes the audio disappear

Here is my code:

```
        AviManager aviManager = new AviManager(aviFilePath, true);
        VideoStream aviStream = aviManager.GetVideoStream();

        VideoStream newStream;
        AviManager newManager = aviStream.DecompressToNewFile(compressedAviPath, true, out newStream);

        aviManager.Close();
        //save and close un-/re-compressed file
        newManager.Close();
```

Do you have any idea how I can:

1. Fix those problems
2. Use another library that can compress AVI videos

Thanks,
Guy.

Comment: You can use DirectShow, which (I think) is going to get you out of C# land. You can call everything from C#, just not natively, if that makes sense. DirectShow AVI Compressor Filter:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318184(v=vs.85).aspx Managed DirectX may have something helpful too. I would try googling.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it seems to be a huge overhead using DirectShow. Are there any other options for compressing AVI video via .net?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [EmguCv](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/2.0.0.0/html/fc05f588-4769-c79d-ef5b-cfe9926701ea.htm)

```
//VideoWriter vw = new public VideoWriter(string fileName, int fps, int width, int height, bool isColor);
VideoWriter vw = new VideoWriter("test.avi", 30, 500, 500, true);
//Then write your frame
vw.WriteFrame(frame);
```